# How to factor $\frac{x^4 - x^3y + 2x^2y^2 - xy^3 + y^4}{x^2 + y^2}$?

Tags: calculus

How to factor $\frac{x^4 - x^3y + 2x^2y^2 - xy^3 + y^4}{x^2 + y^2}$?

I know $x^4 - y^4 = (x^2 + y^2)(x-y)(x+y)$ same as

$x^2 - y^2 = (x-y)(x+y)$

what would be the correct way to factor this?

I'm just asking for the formula to factor this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, to have a factor $x^2+y^2$ you need an $x^2$, with which you get $x^4$ and a term $x^2y^2$, a $y^2$, with which you get $y^4$ and the second $x^2y^2$, and finally a $-xy$ to obtain the remaining terms. So the numerator is
$$(x^2+y^2)(x^2+y^2-xy).$$
Of course this is not a general method, but in this case the decomposition is simple.

Answer (score 2):

$\frac{x^{4} + 2x^{2}y^{2} + y^{4} - x^{3}y - y^{3}x}{x^{2} + y^{2}} = \frac{(x^{2} + y^{2})^{2} - xy(x^{2} + y^{2})}{x^{2} + y^{2}}$$ = \frac{(x^{2} + y^{2})(x^{2} + y^{2} - xy)}{x^{2} + y^{2}} = x^{2} - xy + y^{2}$

Answer (score 0):

Hint: The denominator is $x^2+y^2$. So hopefully that's something we can factor out everywhere. In the numerator we have $x^4$ and $y^4$ (note: not $-y^4$). What's the easiest multiple of $x^2+y^2$ which has both $x^4$ and $y^4$ in it?

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Use $(x^2+y^2)^2 = x^4 + y^4 + 2x^2y^2$ to simplify the numerator.